# Build object［］based on dataset

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I have a list of raw data like following mockData and need to generate to a object[] format, some key-value pair are required from raw data like first, last, state. but some key-value pair are option like nickname. Eventually, I need to build a object array with some same key-value like raw data, and some key's value depends on another key's value like fullname, address. Is there a better way for me to do it and make it more dynamically? because I will have more than 20 different key-value set like fullname, address that need to be built by some function related on raw data
I do not want to create lots of fullname, address type of code

```
export const mockData: Human[] = [
  {
    first: 'name1',
    last: 'v1',
    state: 'ny',
  },
  {
    first: 'name2',
    last: 'v2',
    state: 'pa',
    nickname: 'rocketman',
  }]

export interface Human {
  first: string;
  last: string;
  state: string;
  nickname?: string;
}

export interface Student extends Human{
  fullname: string;
  address: string;
}

function setFullName(first: string, last: string): string {
    return `${first} ${last}`
}

function setAddress(first: string, last: string, state: string): string {
    return `${first} ${last} live a ${state}`
}

function buildStudentData(jsons: Human[]): Student[] {
  return jsons.map((json) =>  <Student> {
      first: json.first,
      last: json.last,
      nickname:  json.hasOwnProperty('nickname') ? json.nickname : json.first,
      fullname: setFullName(json.first, json.last),
      address: setAddress(json.first, json.last, json.state)})
}


console.log(buildStudentData(mockData));
```

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a class instead, where the computed fields are getters:

```
export class Student implements Human {
  public readonly first: string;
  public readonly last: string;
  public readonly state: string;
  public readonly nickname?: string;

  constructor(json: Human) {
    this.first = json.first;
    this.last = json.last;
    this.state = json.state;
    this.nickname = json.nickname;
  }

  public get fullName() {
    return `${this.first} ${this.last}`;
  }

  public get address() {
    return `${this.first} ${this.last} live a ${this.state}`;
  }
}

function buildStudentData(jsons: Human[]): Student[] {
  return jsons.map(json => new Student(json));
}
```

Comment: It's my first thought. But PR for rejected cus developer doesn't like OOD